# Why isn't my method adding up the values in my other classes? (sscce included)

Tags: java, swing, awt

So I'm very new to java.

This program runs right now. It's an ordering system for food. It uses tabs with grids in each. Each tabs has its own prices.

My problem is when I runs and compiles the program, it runs but the prices don't add up.
Basically, in the GUI class listed below, there's a method that takes the prices from each tab and adds them up....except it's not doing that. It does appear but the "$0.00" isn't changing.

Like I said it compiles, however, when I do press buttons, I can see the compiler comes up with this error:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
```

This is the main class:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Pizzamain
{


     public static void main (String[] args)
   {
      JFrame frame = new JFrame ("Pizza Mutt Ordering Service");
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation (JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.getContentPane().add(new PizzaMuttPanel());
      frame.pack();
      frame.setVisible(true);


    }

}
```

This class holds all the GUI. It also adds up the prices in each tab. I commented out the other tabs.

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.text.NumberFormat;

public class PizzaMuttPanel extends JPanel
{
    private JLabel totalLabel;
   private double total;




    public PizzaMuttPanel()
   {
      setLayout (new BorderLayout());

      JLabel name = new JLabel("Pizza Mutt Ordering Service WOOF! WOOF!");
      JPanel namePanel = new JPanel();
      namePanel.add(name);
      add(namePanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);

      JTabbedPane mainTabPane = new JTabbedPane();
      mainTabPane.add("Pizza", new PizzaPanel());
     // mainTabPane.add("Drinks", new DrinksPanel());
     // mainTabPane.add("Specials", new SpecialsPanel());
      add(mainTabPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);

      total = 0.0;
      JPanel totalPanel = new JPanel();
      totalPanel.add (new JLabel("Your total is:"));
      totalLabel = new JLabel("$0.00");
      totalPanel.add(totalLabel);
      add(totalPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

      }



   public void addTotal (double intake)
   {
      total += intake;
      NumberFormat dollars = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
      totalLabel.setText(dollars.format(total));
   }
}
```

This an example of one of the tabs. Btw, ALL the tabs follow this logic. As you can see, in the action section, there's something that adds prices each time a button is pressed then relays the data to the GUI class.

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;


public class PizzaPanel extends JPanel
{
private double price;
private final JButton pl;
private final JButton ps;
private final JButton cl;
private final JButton cs;
private final JButton vl;
private final JButton vs;
private PizzaMuttPanel mainPanel;


   public PizzaPanel()
   {
      setLayout (new GridLayout (2, 3));

      setBackground (Color.red);

      pl = new JButton ("Large Pepperoni: $7");
      ps = new JButton ("Small Pepperoni: $4");
      cl = new JButton ("Large Cheese: $6.50");
      cs = new JButton ("Small Cheese: $3.50");
      vl = new JButton ("Large Vegetable: $7");
      vs = new JButton ("Small Vegetable: $4");

      add (pl);
      add (ps);
      add (cl);
      add (cs);
      add (vl);
      add (vs);



      pl.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());
      ps.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());
      cl.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());
      cs.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());
      vl.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());
      vs.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());



   }  

          //Here we listen for button presses

         private class ButtonListener implements ActionListener
   {
                   public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e)
               {
                 if (e.getSource().equals(pl)) 

                     {

                       price+=7;


                      }

                if(e.getSource().equals(ps)) 

                      {

                         price+=4;


                       } 

                  if (e.getSource().equals(cl)) 
                        {

                         price+=6.5;


                        }

                   if (e.getSource().equals(cs)) 
                        {
                         price+=3.5;


                        } 
                    if (e.getSource().equals(vl)) 
                        {

                         price+=7;


                        }

                   if (e.getSource().equals(vs)) 
                        {

                         price+=4;


                        }
     //This adds all the prices together.                    
                mainPanel.addTotal(price);

        }}}
```

Comment: Your code is not an [sscce](http://sscce.org) since I cannot compile nor run it as posted. It's missing classes. Would it work just as well to have 3 PizzaPanels and get rid of the panels for which you don't show us code? Please clarify.

Comment: Okay, I'll comment them out

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way, perhaps over-kill for you, but which is a very useful technique to know and to use is to make the object that holds the information displayed by the JPanel's a "bound property" which allows other classes the ability to listen for and respond to changes in its state.

Specifically:

- Give your class that holds the info of interest a SwingPropertyChangeSupport field.
- If your class extends JComponent or JPanel (or any class that derives from JComponent), it already has one of these.
- Give your class a private `count` int field
- Give this field a public getter and setter method.
- In the setter field, call the SwingPropertyChangeSupport's `firePropertyChange(String propertyName, int oldValue, int newValue)` method with the updated and the old value.
- **Never** change the bound property directly but only through its setter method.
- Have any class that wants to listen for changes add a PropertyChangeListener to this class.

If you need a more specific example, consider creating and posting an [sscce](http://sscce.org), and I can show you how to modify it to get this to work.

---

**Edit**
Your current code has a problem with references -- you need the sub panels to have a valid reference to the main panel, and you should solve this by passing in a reference.

e.g.

```
private MainPanel mainPanel;

public SubPanelA(MainPanel mainPanel) { 
   this.mainPanel = mainPanel;
```

And then when filling tabs:

```
  mainTabPane.add("A", new SubPanelA(this)); 
  mainTabPane.add("B", new SubPanelB(this)); 
  mainTabPane.add("C", new SubPanelC(this));
```

This way your tab pane classes can call methods from the main class on a valid reference to the displayed main class.

---

**Edit 2**
You state:

> I'm a little confused. But I have a reference, right? In the buttonlistener class, first I private PizzaMuttPanel mainPanel; at the top, and then I referenced it as mainPanel.addTotal(price);. Addtotal is in the main GUI class, and holds the prices. Price is the price being taken from the button presses in that specific tab's classes. Are you saying I should change the latter to: mainTabPane.add("A", new SubPanelA(this));

Points:

- This: `PizzaMuttPanel mainPanel;` is not a reference but rather only a declaration of a reference variable. After declaration, it references null, until you give it a valid reference.
- You state `"and then I referenced it as mainPanel.addTotal(price);"`, ??? this creates no reference whatsoever, and looks to me will only throw a NPE. To give a variable a reference you must **assign** the reference to it, meaning you need some statement that begins `mainPanel = something goes here`.

Comment: I created an SSCCE! It runs, but it's having a small issue.

Comment: @munchschair: thanks for the notification. I will now take a look at it, but also, please edit your original question and tell us what small issue the new code is having.

Comment: Okay, I changed it. Is that accurate?

Comment: I'm a little confused. But I have a reference, right? In the buttonlistener class, first I `private PizzaMuttPanel mainPanel;` at the top, and then I referenced it as `mainPanel.addTotal(price);`. Addtotal is in the main GUI class, and holds the prices. Price is the price being taken from the button presses in that specific tab's classes. Are you saying I should change the latter to: `mainTabPane.add("A", new SubPanelA(this));`

Comment: @munchschair: see **Edit 2**

Comment: But I've seen someone code something similarly. So how about mainPanel += price; in the tabs. Price is declared and being added via user input of buttons. Shouldn't this hold the value?

Comment: @munchschair: 1) that's still an assignment statement. 2) that's dealing with numeric primitives, not reference variables and objects. Please let's stick with your current problem. Your variable will be null if you don't assign an object to it, period. The correct object to assign to it is the visible main JPanel.

Comment: Okay, I'll return to this tomorrow night. Math finals call. I also added an edit. The compiler is giving me this error nullpoint error, but only after it runs.

Comment: @munchschair: exactly, the line that throws the NPE has a variable with a null reference that you're trying to use, and the solution is exactly as I post in my answer above. Good luck with your Math final exam.

Comment: I couldn't resist, I went back. Then I did what you said. IT WORKED OH SWEET MUHHAMAD IT WORKED. I literally just did a dance.

I see how you have to reference it now. I also see why you were using (this). Sort of. Either way, back to math.
THANKS!

Answer (score 2):

So what i understand is that you have three different tabs on a jtabbedpane. And every tab is class that extends JPanel. So you want to add an actionlistener to each tab you only have to implement the interface Actionlistener on each panel, or implement on each button.

```
class tab extends JPanel implements Actionlistener
```

or if you want a specific actionlistener

```
button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    //Action here for the button
        }
});
```

And then you want to get the information from each tab you have to make the variable price public or private. But to access a private variable you have to make getters.

```
public int price;
```

or for the private version.

```
private int price;
public int getPrice(){ return price; }
```

The last one is the preferred way because you cant change the value of the price outside the class that holds that variable.

And for last you want to get the information from all three tabs you can do like this.

```
public void prices()
{
    Tab1 tab1 = new Tab1();
    Tab2 tab2 = new Tab2();
    Tab3 tab3 = new Tab3();

    System.out.println("tab1: " + tab1.price + " tab2: " + tab2.price + " tab3:    " + tab3.price);
    // or if you use getters
    System.out.println("tab1: " + tab1.getPrice() + " tab2: " + tab2.getPrice() + " tab3: " + tab3.getPrice());
}
```

So where do you declare it?

```
class tab extends JPanel implements ActionListener
{
   /*
    * Declare variables here
    */
    private int price;
    private JLabel label;

   /*
    * Methods here
    */
}
```

---

EDIT

The problems is see is that you are checking if the button is clicked by its text not the variable. And the other thing is that you are giving a new instance of the button listener every time. Instead of creating a new class called ButtonListener we are just implement the interface ActionListener on the PizzaPanel class.

```
public class PizzaPanel extends JPanel implements ActionListener{

private JButton b1 = null;
private JButton b2 = null;

private int Price;

public int getPrice() {
    return Price;
}

public PizzaPanel() {
    b1 = new JButton("B1");
    b2 = new JButton("B2");

    b1.addActionListener(this);
    b2.addActionListener(this);

    add(b1);
    add(b2);
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if(e.getSource().equals(b1)){
        Price++;
        System.out.println("Button 1 clicked");
    }
    if(e.getSource().equals(b2))
    {
        Price--;
        System.out.println("Button 2 clicked");
    }
}
}
```

Comment: You got it dude, I'm going to go apply this to my program and see what happens.

Comment: Where should I set up the label that stores all this information?

Comment: If you use implements ActionListener on the class you have to tell what components(button,etc) to use it. For example button.addActionListener(this); And you can also add many ActionListeners to each component but i recommend to only use one in this case.

Comment: No I mean, should I be making jLabel for each panel or just in the driver main class? I'm gonna post my code soon.

Eh, I'm making if else statements to gather which buttons are being pressed. I'm not sure if this is necessary.

Comment: If you want the jlabel on the panel make(declare and init) it on the panel. So tab1 should have a variable called JLabel label and same for tab2,tab3.

Comment: Okay, so I posted my progress, I don't want individual panes for the price for each panel, I just want to grab it and display the price in my main driver class.